# Use rspec / capybara to test that css element has received correct attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara

In my rails application I ask a user for their favorite color.  They select a value (a hex input).  The color is saved (eg. #D2D2D2) and then applied as the background-color element to a predefined css class:

```
<html>
 <body>
   <style>
     .favorite_color { background-color: #D2D2D2; } /* updated dynamically <%= @user.favorite_color %> */
   </style>
   <div class="favorite_color">My favorite color</div>
   <div class="some_content">Some content</div>
   <div class="favorite_color">My favorite color again</div>
 </body>
```

Everything works fine, but I am wondering now how to test that the saved value is correctly applied as the background-color wherever the div appears.

I have tried (using rspec and capybara):
    p page.find('.favorite_color')[:style]

but I end up with nil as the output.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might get the background-color so I can test it is correctly applied?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should fill it in and expect it to be there when you revisit the page.

```
fill_in 'the_id_of_the_input_field', with: '#D2D2D2'

expect(page).to have_field('the_id_of_the_input_field', with: '#D2D2D2')
```

or if you prefer to use the class

```
fill_in '.favorite_color', with: '#D2D2D2'

expect(page).to have_field('.favorite_color', with: '#D2D2D2')
```